# modelling uncertain exchanges in brightway using parameters

Tags: brightway

I am trying to define uncertain exchanges using parameters with Brightway25. I've created a very simle example following existing ones that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of excel file with LCI]
The database with this single activity imports fine with `write_database(activate_parameters=True)`

The database seems to import ok with `write_database(activate_parameters=True)` but if I go to the biosphere exchange of co2 and try to use the method `random_sample` I get all nans. I was hoping that method could "pick up" the uncertainty defined in the activity parameters. I have the same problem with CH4. For the N2O exchange, where I defined the uncertainty *directly* on the exchange the `random_sample` method works fine. It seems as only the uncertainty around N2O is being considered. Is this a limitation of the parameterisation or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @cmutel :-) ? any hint about this ?

Comment: I've found out a ParameterSet has a method evaluate_monte_carlo. Is there a easy way to create a parameter set from parameters associated with bwdata activities ? @ChrisMutel?

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005772/4827616) suggests that parameters are not to be used with Monte-Carlo, but the `evaluate_monte_carlo()` method really looks like something to use parameter uncertainty for Monte-Carlo...